# Do the yearly (worldcomp) conference recognized by Scientists?

Tags: publications, ranking, conference

I am planning to submit for a conference that organized by the (World Congress in Computer Science, Computer Engineering, & Applied Computing https://americancse.org/events/csce2018) located and held every year in the US. Looking at their invited speakers over the last 10 years, they managed to attract many top scientists from NASA, SAP, Google...etc

The conference that I am planning to submit my work for named `The 20th Int'l Conf on Artificial Intelligence (ICAI'18)` and ranked-B according to Qualis. After I checked the dblp database, I noticed that they stoped indexing the Congress proceeding on their website. Do that indicate or reflect any bad signs?

Comment: Have you tried asking your supervisor or colleagues if they think this is a good conference?

Comment: Yes, they refused it only because it not ranked by Core rank. I do not believe that their judgment is correct...

Comment: I have trouble deciphering exactly what you mean - the title : do you mean "is X conference recognised" or should you "do" ie go to that conference as it is recognised?